# How can I suppress xml:base attribute that the java.xml Transformer is adding to imported external system entities?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom, xml-parsing

There must be an xslt or xalan property for this, but I cannot find it.

Let's say I have an xml file that declares an external system entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE stuff [
        <!ENTITY imported_fragment SYSTEM "fragment.xml">
        ]>
<stuff>
    <innerstuff name="a">
        <lala>Hello!</lala>
    </innerstuff>

    &imported_fragment;
</stuff>
```

fragment looks like:

```
<innerstuff name="b">
    <lala>Bye!</lala>
</innerstuff>
```

If I read this in with the javax.xml classes and write it back out, I get:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<stuff>
    <innerstuff name="a">
        <lala>Hello!</lala>
    </innerstuff>

    <innerstuff name="b" xml:base="file:/full/path/to/fragment.xml">
        <lala>Bye!</lala>
    </innerstuff>
</stuff>
```

Note the attribute `xml:base` that it added.  How do I suppress this?

Here is the code I use to read and write the xml file:

```
    Document dom;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        sLogger.info("Parsing file: " + fInputFile);
        dom = db.parse(fInputFile);
    } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
       //...
    }

    try {
        Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
        //tr.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        File outputFile = new File(fOutputDirectory, fInputFile.getName());
        sLogger..info("Writing xml output to: " + outputFile);

        tr.transform(new DOMSource(dom), 
                 new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)));

    } catch (IOException | TransformerException e) {
        //...
    }
```

edit:  joepie's answer worked.  Here is the java code that incorporates his XSLT

```
     try {
        Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
        tr.transform(new DOMSource(dom), domResult);

        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("removexmlbase.xslt"));
        Transformer tr2 = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(source);
        tr2.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        tr2.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        tr2.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        tr2.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
        //tr2.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        File outputFile = new File(fOutputDirectory, fXMLFile.getName());
        getLog().info("Writing xml output to: " + outputFile);
        // send DOM to file
        tr2.transform(new DOMSource(domResult.getNode()), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)));

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XSLT 1.0 template to suppress the xml:base attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Suppress xml:base attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@xml:base"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**[Working Example](http://xsltransform.net/bFukv89/1)**

Comment: thanks, this worked and I was able to incorporate it into my java.

Comment: Note that this means the xml:base wasn't added by the Transformer, it was added by the parser.